# How to use WITH with an array of ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set the borders for a bunch of ranges.

This is how I do it:

```
For n = 1 to record_num
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & (n-1)*3 + 1 & ":C" & (n-1)*3 + 2)
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ThemeColor = 6
            .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    ... some other border codes
    End With
Next n
```

Because `For ... Next` is always slow, I'm thinking of putting the ranges in an array and set the borders all at once.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For n = 1 to record_num
        Set cellArray(i) = .Range("A" & (n-1)*3 + 1 & ":C" & (n-1)*3 + 2)
    Next i
End With
```

This loop works fine. I then tried to do a `With cellArray()`, `With Range(cellArray())`, `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cellArray())` and they all failed with the error message of "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed".

What is the proper syntax of doing it?

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow but I think you want Union(rng1,rn2.....)

Comment: Why are you using a `For` loop? It is a contiguous range so directly mention the complete range. Something like `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C" & record_num + 2)... End With`

Comment: @Siddharth Thanks for catching that one. After trying so many things, I'm kind of lost.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks. You're right. Union works the wonder.

Comment: But why are you trying to create a union of contiguous range? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Siddharth Sorry that I did not mention it. I have edited the question. The loop is now slightly different, the range no longer contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Format With Offset

[Range.Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub formatWithOffset()
    
    Dim record_num As Long
    ' e.g.;
    record_num = 5
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C2")
    
    Dim tRng As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To record_num
        If Not tRng Is Nothing Then
            Set tRng = Union(tRng, rng.Offset((n - 1) * 3))
        Else
            Set tRng = rng
        End If
    Next n
    
    If Not tRng Is Nothing Then
        With tRng
            With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 6
                .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
                .Weight = xlThick
            End With
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `With` with an array, you need to iterate through each element of the array individually, as the `With` operator only operates on a single object.

This assigns the ranges to the `cellarray`:

```
Dim cellarray(1 To 5) As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For n = 1 To 5
        Set cellarray(n) = .Range("A" & (n - 1) * 3 + 1 & ":C" & (n - 1) * 3 + 2)
    Next n
End With
```

and then run through the elements of `cellarray`, and use `With` to apply the styles.

```
For Each c In cellarray
    With c
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 12
    End With
Next c
```

Comment: Then, there is little or no difference with my original method. Can't an array be treated as a single object?

Comment: An Array is a single object, but arrays don't tend to have many properties, and in your case, it isn't a Range, so it doesn't have the properties of a Range - you need to access the individual Range elements to access the properties.